# Remote desktop into macOS from Windows

Tags: macos, windows, remote-desktop

I am doing some development on my MacBook and I would like to use my desktop to access it remotely as I have a dual monitor setup. Is there a way to do this? My desktop is Windows and my Mac is a 2015 Retina MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 2):

Download [RealVNC Viewer](https://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/) for Windows and move it to the applications folder.

In the macOS open System Preferences > Sharing and enable "Screen Sharing" for either *All users* or restrict it to your user.

Open RealVNC Viewer and enter the IP or the host name of the Mac and hit the enter key.

Comment: Does RealVNC allow for multi monitor output through rdp? Or do I have to get a cable?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is TeamViewer. You can setup TeamViewer with "unattended access". Be sure to use a really good password, but this should do the trick for you. You can read more about it here:
https://www-rc.teamviewer.com/en/use-cases/remote-access/